# Running time of algorithm with arbitrary sized recursive calls

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures, graph, big-o

I have written the following algorithm that given a node x in a Binary Search Tree T, will set the field s for all nodes in the subtree rooted at x, such that for each node, s will be the sum of all odd keys in the subtree rooted  in that node.

```
OddNodeSetter(T, x):
    if (T.x == NIL):
        return 0;
    if (T.x.key mod 2 == 1):
        T.x.s = T.x.key + OddNodeSetter(T, x.left) + OddNodeSetter(T, x.right)
    else:
        T.x.s = OddNodeSetter(T, x.left) + OddNodeSetter(T, x.right)
```

I've thought of using the master theorem for this, with the recurrence

```
T(n) = T(k) + T(n-k-1) + 1 for 1 <= k < n
```

however since the size of the two recursive calls could vary depending on k and n-k-1 (i.e. the number of nodes in the left and right subtree of x), I can't quite figure out how to solve this recurrence though. For example in case the number of nodes in the left and right subtree of x are equal, we can express the recurrence in the form

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1
```

which can be solved easily, but that doesn't prove the running time in all cases.

Is it possible to prove this algorithm runs in O(n) with the master theorem, and if not what other way is there to do this?

Comment: I think that function should return something, since you are using its return value. (And then there may not be any need to save the value in every node.)

Comment: The algorithm is called on the root of a tree inside another algorithm to set field s for every node, it is the intended use.)

Comment: ok, but `OddNodeSetter(T, x.left) + OddNodeSetter(T, x.right)
` has no value unless `OddNodeSetter` returns something :)

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm visits every node in the tree exactly once, hence O(N).

---

**Update:**

And obviously, a visit takes constant time (not counting the recursive calls).

Comment: Thank you for the response, but how can I formally prove that the algorithm does indeed visit every node exactly once?

Comment: @BasirDoost: it is obvious that when the function is called with some element, its left and right sons are always visited as well. This is enough to guarantee exhaustive traversal. And inductively, every element is visited once and so are its subtrees (one call left, one call right).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the Master theorem here.

Think of the problem this way: what is the maximum number of operations you have do for each node in the tree? It is bounded by a constant. And what the is the number of nodes in the tree? It is *n*.

The multiplication of constant with *n* is still *O(n)*.

Comment: Misleading argument. This holds iff the nodes are visited no more than a constant number of times. This is an essential "detail".

Comment: @YvesDaoust How is counting the number of operations per node wrong? Surely it would still be *O(n)* is each node was visited 2 times or 3 times, but it's *O(n)* **if and only if** the number of operations per node is bounded by a constant.

Comment: for this you need to have that the number of visits is itself bounded by a constant, which you didn't address.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If the number of visits per node is not not bounded by a constant, then surely the number of operations is surely not bounded by constant, too. Whatever... I feel sorry for myself too.